# how to add credentials for a branch in git

Tags: git

I want to add a username and a password for a branch I am working on so no one would edit/clone the branch unless they know the credentials, is it possible? if not is there any other way to approach this?

Comment: Note that hosting providers like GitHub usually have their own add-ons for features such as protected branches. How these work depends on the hosting provider, since the add-ons are not built in to Git itself.

Comment: thank you will work on the GitHub to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is "no".

Branches in git don't really "own" anything, they're just a pointer to a commit, and from there to the history of that commit. They also don't really exist outside a particular copy of a repository - there are commands for copying the pointers from one repo to another (fetch, pull, push) but you can also just copy the commits and give them your own name.

A common way to have a *read-only* branch is to have a central copy of the repository, and put permissions on who can make changes to that. For instance, if you use Github to host your central copy, you can use its "protected branches" feature to limit who can commit to certain branches (which per the previous paragraph means "move the pointer for that branch name on that copy").

If you want the branch to actually be *secret* (you mention preventing cloning) you'll need a copy of the repository that only some people can access. Again, this could be on something like Github or Gitlab, which will handle the authentication for you. You can then have a branch on that copy which *by your own convention* you never push to more open copies.

The simplest version of this if you're the *only* person who should have access is to just keep it in your local copy and never push it anywhere: as far as git is concerned, your local copy is just another clone, and can have whatever new branches and commits you want. If you're worried you might lose it, just take backups of the whole copy, including the .git directory.

Comment: thank you for your answer, and I apologize if I wasn't clear but I would like for certain people to access that repo, so I could have the final code in that branch but I don't want anyone to access it unless they are authorized to. is there away to do that? if yes can I have the command line for that or do I need to use github as you recommend it

Comment: @SHA If you want to share the code at all, you need some central copy - that could be on a service like Github or Gitlab, or on a server in your own network just running git itself. How you restrict access to that is going to depend how you share it, and there certainly isn't anything you can type in your _local_ copy that will somehow protect that _shared_ copy.